How do I set the Orientation/Rotation for a WEBP?
I'm trying to rotate a WEBP without having to recompress it.
The best way I can think of is by simply setting metadata to change its orientation.
How do I set the Orientation/Rotation metadata for a WEBP?
I several things with exiftool and webpmux, but I just don't seem to get anything to work.
Does WEBP even support Orientation as metadata?
The documentation of webpmux doesn't mention anything about rotation or orientation.

I used this exiftool on a webp file which writes the EXIF:Orientation  tag (webp supports both EXIF and XMP metadata)
exiftool -Orientation="Rotate 180" file.webp
When viewed with XNViewMP, it was correctly inverted. Irfanview, on the other hand, did not rotate it. Irfanview also didn't display any metadata when checked, so it apparently doesn't read the metadata in webp files and therefor doesn't know the image has to be rotated.
Checking Chrome and Firefox, neither of them rotated the image correctly either.
You might have to check with each of the programs you use to see if they support reading the Orientation in the file or not.

Thank you very much. Yeah, in the one time I got a successful return code from my various command tests (and no stderr either), the image wasn't rotating either. It's important to work on browsers, since that's why I'm using WEBP. This means rotation as metadata is not supported, and therefore shouldn't be used, then. Many thanks!

My quick searches suggested that you could use CSS to rotate it for web browsers. But now the main result from Google on the subject is this question

Thanks. Yeah, exactly - Google and users saving the images. I really want to rotate the image itself :) -- I guess my only option is to recompress it, then! Unfortunately that will reduce the quality of the image, but...
